# Access to all glyphs from OTF font in Photoshop CS6 (Mac OS)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, font-management

I have downloaded font and saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCtZ0CaseTM). Here author show, how to use all glyphs in Illustrator. But how to use it in Photoshop? I tried to find symbols in Fonts.app, copy it and paste to photoshop but it appear as square with cross. Help please :)

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop doesn't have a glyphs window but all glyphs have a keyboard shortcut (usually alt+something)

[Here's a pretty good reference](http://typefacts.com/keyboard-shortcuts)

Or just look for the shortcut in Google..

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has very patchy support of OpenType glyphs and without knowing which version you're running it's hard to give 100% accurate advice.

Here's a couple of workarounds I'd try:

- Use the OS X'Character Viewer' app instead of the Fonts app to select and copy the glyphs you want. Make sure to select 'Special Characters' from the Edit  menu.
- Use Illustrator to copy and paste the glyphs across.